# JavaScript libraries do not work when using localhost addressing

Tags: javascript, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea, tinymce

I am working with **IntelliJ Idea** and **Apache TomCat**. Simple jsp and html files work fine. but when using a javascript library like **Tinymce**, it does not work using **(localhost:8080/tiny.html)**. However, it works using **(file:///C:/Test1/web/tiny.html)**.

I used the following to specify the js file:

```
  <script src="WEB-INF/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

But when I use the cloud version. it works fine even with localhost:8080:

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help understand what could the problem be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't retrieve any file in the `/WEB-INF` folder of a Java web application through just URL addressing. Your JS code must be outside of this folder, the URL adjusted - then it works.

Tomcat rightfully rejects delivering such files.